# How to count number of bars between 2 candles that meet distinct conditions respectively in pine-script

Tags: count, pine-script, pine-script-v5

Given 2 true false conditions A and B
I would like to search for the low of all the candles between these 2 conditions.
the script load, but an error say *"invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the "lowest" function. it must be >0"*

Could someone help please? Thanks

```
var int nb_bars = 0
nb_bars := B? ta.barssince(A)[2] : 0     // I have [2] because condition A could trigger just before condition B, I want to search the A which is further away
ClusterLow =  B ? ta.lowest(nb_bars) : na
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, you cannot set the `length` to zero.

And `ta.barssince(A)[2]` can also be zero if condition A happened 2 bars ago from now, then it happened 0 bars back 2 bars ago. If you skew the index with `[2]`, you have to skew the length parameter as well.

Try `ClusterLow =  B ? ta.lowest(nb_bars + 2) : na`